# ArcGIS Pro dialog boxes are not visible after updating to 3.1.1 from 2.8

Tags: arcgis-pro

I updated ArcGIS Pro to 3.1.1 from 2.8, and now I cannot see any of the usual dialog boxes when trying to use the software--Save As, Folder Connections, etc--*anything* that ordinarily generates a dialog box does not generate anything. I'm running Windows 10 Home (21H2) on a Dell XPS 13 7390, connected to a Dell WD15 dock with two external monitors. The problem persists whether the monitors are connected or not.

If you have encountered this, then how did you solve it?

Comment: Try changing the screen resolution with the dialog boxes open, this should force their repositioning from off-screen to centre of main screen and then change the resolution back to the optimal setting. ArcGIS Pro should then remember where your forms should appear.

Comment: This worked! Thank you Michael for the suggestion, sorry it took so long to close the loop!